# How to get day month and year in integer from given string date in pattern dd-MMM-yyyy

Tags: java, android

I have a string date in format `(dd-MMM-yyyy)` like (23-SEP-2019). I want to seperate day month and year from above string in **integer** like **day = 23, month = 09, year = 2019**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
String pattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date date = simpelDateFormat.parse(yourdateString);
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.setTime(date);
int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; // Note: zero based!
int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: but date.getYear is a deprecated method in android

Comment: You can use Calendar class or 3-rd party library.

Comment: I would not recommend importing extra libraries for something this simple. Not only is it hassle, but you will probably be importing much more than you actually need with far less knowledge of what could go wrong.

Comment: modified with Calendar

Comment: Thanks @yuan qingfei

Comment: it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this, but I would go with this:

```
//convert it to a char array.
char[] asChars = dateString.toCharArray();
//Parse the date and year and from new strings.
int dayVal = Interger.ParseInt(""+asChars[0]+asChars[1]);
int yearVal = Interger.ParseInt(""+asChars[7]+asChars[8]+asChars[9]+asChars[10]);
//use a switch for the month.
int monthVal = 0;
String monthString = ""+asChars[3]+asChars[5]+asChars[6];
switch (monthString) {
    case "JAN" :
        monthVal = 1;
        break;
    case "FEB" :
        monthVal = 2;
        break;
    case "MAR"  :
        monthVal = 3;
        break;
    case "APR" :
        monthVal = 4;
        break;
    case "MAY" :
        monthVal = 5;
        break;
    case "JUN" :
        monthVal = 6;
        break;
    case "JUL" :
        monthVal = 7;
        break;
    case "AUG" :
        monthVal = 8;
        break;
    case "SEP" :
        monthVal = 9;
        break;
    case "OCT" :
        monthVal = 10;
        break;
    case "NOV" :
        monthVal = 11;
        break;
    case "DEC" :
        monthVal = 12;
        break;
}
```

You'll need to put that in a try block and you'll want a catch for NumberFormatException and IndexOutOfBounds, in both cases the string was formatted incorrectly.

You will also separately need to check that the month string matched a month, so either add a default case to the switch or have a check that monthVal>0 after all that.

If you really want to be sure the original string was formatted correctly (which is a separate issue but I think still relevant) then you could check the string is of length 11 before all of that.

Comment: this code is too long

Comment: I don't see much room for shortening it without just using a different approach. Why is the length of the code a problem for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use java 8 LocalDate feature. I provide below the code, you can check.

```
String dateStr = "23-Sep-2019";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter_1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(dateStr, formatter_1);
    System.out.println("localDate_1 = " + localDate);
    int day = localDate.getDayOfMonth();
    int month = localDate.getMonthValue();
    int year = localDate.getYear();
    System.out.println(day + "-" + month + "-" + year);
```